# Magento checking if product is available in multiple sites

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have a magento-setup with multiple websites and multiple stores and i want to check if stores contain the same product programmaticly. Because i am writing a module for it I rewrite the product block so i can acces `$this->product()->getid()` with no problem. I checked the list (`$this->product()`) for websites but i cant find it there. Any idea how i start with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried ?

```
$this->product()->getWebsiteIds();
```

It will give you an array of website ids the product is active on.

You can also do,

```
$this->product()->getStoreIds();
```